# Biblatex problem with authoryear-comp style

Tags: biblatex

I'm having an unexpected problem with the `authoryear-comp` style in Biblatex. See this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,firstinits=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage[autostyle=false, style=british]{csquotes}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @article{JoeDoe2012,
    Author = {Joe Doe},
    Title = {My article's title},
    Journal = {My journal's title},
    Editor = {Ben Editor},
    URL = {http://webpage.com},
  }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  \cite{JoeDoe2012}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

When I compile, instead of getting `Doe 2012` when citing, I get the article's title.

[image]

Is there something (obvious) I'm forgetting here?

Comment: I don't get any errors. If I remove `firstinits=true`, I don't get the warning you mention, but still get the citation wrong. I'm using `Biber`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing the year/date field in your bibliography entry.

Comment: That's right! As `Biblatex`'s documentation explains, `authoryear-comp` requires both the `author` and the `year` field; otherwise it default citing the title. Thanks for noticing.